# Use EasyBlog's autoposting from external PHP

Tags: php, joomla, easyblog

I'm trying to autopost an **EasyBlog** blog post from my own component to Twitter.  I currently have:

```
$blog = EasyBlogHelper::getTable( 'Blog' );
$blog->load( $postId );
$blog->autopost(array('twitter'));
```

`autopost` says it's successful, but the post isn't showing up on Twitter, nor is there an indicator in the backend of my Joomla site.  I don't get any error messages.

What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Just an aside: I'm not familiar with EasyBlog but I'm interested to see how one would debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was using EB's API incorrectly.  The final line should be:

```
$blog->autopost(array('twitter'), array('twitter'));
```